# Calling Methods in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 2.3.2 and I am really miss something important in here.

I got some .rb files in my lib folder and in one of them, I got a line saying

```
User.new(x,y,z)
```

But when I go to the user.rb which is also sitting in lib folder, I don't find any method with defined with new. When I look at the initializer, it just assigns the incoming attributes to the variables like

```
def initialize(x,y,z)
  @x = x
  @y = y
  @z = z
end
```

Can you guys please tell me what I am really missing here. I know I am missing something really important.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby (not only Rails) calling `ClassName.new()` invokes `initialize` method from this class to ... well.. initialize the object created. The `initialize` method will be passed all the arguments that are passed to `new()`

See here for details: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html

Comment: So, Other than that nothing is going to happen?

Comment: Other than object being created and values of arguments assigned to class variables? Nope.

Comment: The `initialize` method is automatically called with the arguments you pass to `new`, so whatever is in that method will be executed when you call `new`.

Comment: Thank you guys. So I am not missing anything :)